# String to Integer Error

Tags: java, string, integer

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        File f = new File("C:/Users/asus/IdeaProjects/whatt/src/food.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);

        List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();

        while(sc.hasNextLine()){
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            String[] details = line.split("\t");
            int serial = Integer.parseInt(details[0]);
            String name = details[1];
            int age = Integer.parseInt(details[2]);
            Person p = new Person(serial, name, age);
            people.add(p);
        }

        for(Person p: people){
            System.out.println(p.toString());
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
 class Person{

private int serial;
private String name;
private int age;

public Person(int serial, String name, int age){
    this.serial = serial;
    this.setName(name);
    this.age = age;
}


public int getserial() {
    return serial;
}


public void setserial(int serial) {
    this.serial = serial;
}


public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}


public int getAge() {
    return age;
}


public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public String toString(){
    return this.serial + " " + this.name + " " + this.age;
}


}
```

1001  elma    87

1002  muz 98

1003  avocado 221

1004  blackberry  64

1005  armut   79

1006  ayva    91

1007  erik    65

I have txt file like this.It contains 2 integer and 1 string.Im trying to convert these strings to integer but "1001" always give java.lang.NumberFormatException error.What can I do to fix this?

Comment: sure it's \t and not \s or \s+ between your words ?, try print Arrays.toString(details) after split to check

Comment: Is your text file separated by tabs or spaces?

Comment: @Jacob seperated by tabs

Comment: @azro I did it it shows like "1001\telma\t87"

Comment: Add a `println` after you split, make sure there are actually 3 elements.

Comment: YEe issue is in File Format. Split returns more than 3 elements.

Comment: Print like `System.out.println(">" + details[0] + "<")` to check spaces

Comment: You might be using a text editor that translates tabs to 4 (or 3, or n) spaces. Most IDEs do that. Check if `line.contains("\t")` returns true.

Comment: And even its tab you can use \s+ as regex (\\s+ in the string)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `String.split()` takes a regex. So it is not actually splitting on tabs. Try making the argument `\\t` so that you escape the backslash. This will allow the regex to properly parse.

Comment: still gives an Error in 1001 which is the first word in line.

Comment: Check that your text file is actually using tabs and not spaces or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of depending on \t, \n or \r, try java Regex. It would be a better approach to extract your numbers.

for example like this: `(^[0-9]*)\\s*[Aa-zZ]*\\s*([0-9]*)`

the first `(^[0-9]*)` capture the first String
the second `([0-9]*)` capture the second String

```
// String to be scanned to find the pattern.
  String line = "1001 elma 87";
  String pattern = "(^[0-9]*)\\s*[Aa-zZ]*\\s*([0-9]*)";

  // Create a Pattern object
  Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

  // Now create matcher object.
  Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
  if (m.find( )) {
      int first = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
      int second = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
     System.out.println("first int " + first );
     System.out.println("second int " +second);
  }
```

it would print out:

```
first int 1001
second int 87
```

that is what regex are for: *identify* and *extracting* part of your strings